# Не правильный импорт из библиотеки strapi/design-system

Tags: typescript, strapi

В существующий проект нужно внедрить стили взятые из библиотеки strapi, но всю библиотеку ставить нет возможности потому что проєкт уже существует и  делать єто так как предлагает strapi нет возможности, по єтому с горем пополам была найдена  их библиотека которая по идее отдает только компоненты на по типу как это делает MUI. Проект на Typescript и так как предлагается подключить библиотеку не получается поскольку ТС ругается на Types которых нет. И объявить модуль я что то не могу помогите кто сталкивался с похожей задачей! На npm есть @strapi/types но єто не решает проблему вообще после того как поставил нечего не изменилось.[image: tsconfig.json]
[image: strapi.d.ts и index.ts]

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)